# Проверка на наличие нескольких символов в строке в определенном порядке. Питон

Tags: python, строки, list

Есть список b, состоящий из нескольких строк. Нужно проверить содержится ли в каждой конкретной строке слово (например, 'anton'). Должны быть буквы этого слова, не обязательно подряд (**даже чаще не подряд** - т.е. такая строка подходит: '**a**sr**n**gk**t**nv5j**on**j'), но именно в этом порядке. В слове совпадают последняя и третья с конца буквы.
В моей "изящной" конструкции такой код:

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    if ('a' in b[i] and 't' in b[i] and 'o' in b[i] and b[i].count('n') >= 2 and b[i].find('a') < b[i].find('n') < b[i].find('t') < b[i].find('o') < b[i].rfind('n')):
        print(i + 1, end=' ')
```

В нем я проверяю наличие каждой из букв в строке списка, а очередность - через сравнение значений индексов.

Проблема:

1. проверка на наличие букв тяжеловесная.
2. код не работает - в тестах где в строках много разных символов этот код где-то находит искомое слово, а где-то не находит (хотя нужные буквы и нужной последовательности там имеются).

Отсюда два вопроса:

- как проверить наличие букв в строке более компактно. Вообще, можно ли сделать конструкцию, в которой бы был список или кортеж из искомых символов и они искались в строке. Типа:
  `if ('a', 'n', 't', 'o') in b` - ?
- как проверить располагаются ли эти символы в нужной последовательности? (помня, что в искомом слове есть еще две одинаковые буквы)?

P.S. что касается проверки, делал ее в том числе и через срезы, типа:

```
for i in b:
    while b[i] != 'a':
        b[i] = b[i][1:]
    count += 1
```

перебирал нужные буквы, пока не находилась искомая я удалял первый символ строки. Когда буква находилась - к счетчику добавлял 1. В итоге при `count = 5` условие выполнялось. Но, тут тоже результат нулевой.

Comment: А чем не подошла проверка через in? ``if 'anton' in string: ... `` по идее должен сработать

Comment: Сразу подумал (а что, так можно было??). Проверил - выдает только те строки, где эти буквы подряд. А они могут идти и не подряд.

Comment: @biflé тем, что это ищет подстроку "anton", а не отдельные символы

Comment: Понял, видимо, сначала не въехал в условие) Я-то думал, что нужно просто проверить на наличие слова в строке)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант с регуляркой

```
import re

lines = ['asrngktnv5jonj', 'asrngkfnv5jonj', 'afdjflewkjcneckdbctlbnldjcodsnnnnnnnnnnn']
text = 'anton'
r = re.compile('.*'.join(re.escape(text)))
for line in lines:
    if r.search(line):
        print(f'Строка `{line}` содержит `{text}`')
    else:
        print(f'Строка `{line}` НЕ содержит `{text}`')
```

```
Строка `asrngktnv5jonj` содержит `anton`
Строка `asrngkfnv5jonj` НЕ содержит `anton`
Строка `afdjflewkjcneckdbctlbnldjcodsnnnnnnnnnnn` содержит `anton`
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас проверю в программе.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо, добавил. На всякий :)

Comment: '.*' -> '.*?'. Не жадный образец будет давать те же результаты быстрее.

Comment: Спасибо! Сегодня на свежую голову придумал как сделать вывод. И понял что надо срочно учить регулярки))

Answer (score 2):

Двигаясь по образцу `subseq` ищем следующий символ в тексте. Поиск начинается со следующей позиции в тексте (переменная `i`):

```
def is_subseq(subseq, text):
    i = -1
    for c in subseq:
        i = text.find(c, i + 1)
        if i == -1:
            return False
    return True


print(is_subseq('anton', 'anton'))
print(is_subseq('anton', 'asrngktnv5jonj'))
print(is_subseq('anton', 'asrngkfnv5jonj'))
print(is_subseq('anton', 'afdjflewkjcneckdbctlbnldjcodsnnnnnnnnnnn'))
```

> ```
> $ python subseq.py
> True
> True
> False
> True
> ```